# how to determine the length of the output from oracle standard_hash function?

Tags: oracle, hash

May I ask how to determine the size output from oracle standard_hash function?

I have following table

```
Create table Tbl1 (
ID number,
Col_1 Varchar2(3000),
Col_2 Varchar2(3000),
Col_3 Varchar2(3000),
Col_30 Varchar2(3000),
Std_hash raw(**1000**)
);
```

(The table have 30 varchar2(3000) columns. We just obmitted some columns in the here)

And following update statements

```
update tbl1 set
std_hash = standard_hash (
    ID|| 
    nvl(Col_1 ,'') ||
    nvl(Col_2,'') ||
    nvl(Col_30,'')
);
```

I tried to use the max and length function to determine the maximum length of the values stored in the std_hash and I got 40

```
select max(length(std_hash)) from tbl1

MAX(LENGTH(STD_HASH))
---------------------
**40**
```

The column STD_Hash stores the hash value of every rows in the table. Does it means I have originally over estimated the size of the output length of the hash value from Standard hash when create the table tbl1 by putting Raw (**1000**)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you're actually doing.

`STANDARD_HASH` accepts two arguments; you provided the first, but didn't provide the **method** (name of the hash algorithm). Valid values are:

- SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, MD5

Default is SHA1.

A little bit of testing:

```
SQL> select
  2    length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA1'))   sha1,
  3    length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA256')) sha256,
  4    length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA384')) sha384,
  5    length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA512')) sha512,
  6    length(standard_hash('x', 'MD5'))    md5
  7  from dual;

      SHA1     SHA256     SHA384     SHA512        MD5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        40         64         96        128         32

SQL>
```

As you didn't use the method, SHA1 is being used and the result's length is `40` - value you noticed. It means that you could have created the column as

```
Std_hash raw(40)
```

instead of `1000`. However, if you decide to specify another method, column size might need to be changed (from 32 to 128).

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot. Thanks a lot! Yes I am using the default option only. Just one more question, would my over estimation cost me a lot of spaces? Say if I specify Raw(1000), would it means the database will allocate the spaces required for Raw(1000) (like the CHAR datatype) or it will still be variant (like the Varchar2 datatype)? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. As Documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) says, "RAW is a variable-length datatype like the VARCHAR2 character datatype".

Comment: Thank you for your help! You have helped me on solving my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `standard_hash()` function return type is `RAW` (byte data). By using the `length()` function you are causing an implicit cast to a (hex-ascii) string which ends up being 2x the `RAW` value's length.

To obtain the actual length of the `standard_hash()` function's native `RAW` output, use `utl_raw.length()` as below:

```
select
  utl_raw.length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA1'))   sha1,
  utl_raw.length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA256')) sha256,
  utl_raw.length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA384')) sha384,
  utl_raw.length(standard_hash('x', 'SHA512')) sha512,
  utl_raw.length(standard_hash('x', 'MD5'))    md5
from dual;

      SHA1     SHA256     SHA384     SHA512        MD5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        20         32         48         64         16
```

With this in mind, you should create the column as:

```
Std_hash raw(20)
```

*Not raw(40) as suggested by the previous answer.*

References:

- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71404
- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647
- [how to determine the length of the output from oracle standard_hash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541270/how-to-determine-the-length-of-the-output-from-oracle-standard-hash-function)